# How to add App Reviews option in my website?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app

I have a Shopify App and I run a website as well. I plan to take ratings and reviews for my App from my Website.

I want to find a way where I can add a pop-up kind of thing that lets registered users give reviews and ratings for my app from my Website, which will show up in Shopify App page.